# Libgdx FileHandle list() method doesn't work in jar file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, libgdx

I created a desktop game in eclipse using Libgdx. The game runs great in eclipse, however the FileHandle `list()` method doesn't work when exported to a jar file. I used the following lines of code:

```
songFiles = Gdx.files.internal("./bin/" + "songs/").list();
System.out.println(songFiles[0]);
```

Again, in eclipse it prints the file location.However when exported to a jar, I get a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` error.

[Cannot export default Java libGDX project as a jar from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36972509/cannot-export-default-java-libgdx-project-as-a-jar-from-eclipse) looks similar to the issue that I am having

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: No, the problem is that the list() method doesn't operate the same as it does in eclipse. I think that it is something to do with the file structure when a project is exported to a jar file.

Comment: I was about to write something like this but can't figure out what exactly the problem is.

Comment: To quote the javadocs: "On the desktop, an Files.FileType.Internal handle to a directory on the classpath will return a zero length array.". https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandle.html#list--. Or to quote the wiki: "Listing of internal directories is not supported on Desktop." https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling#listing-and-checking-properties-of-files.

Answer (score 0):

It says you created the list or array but u didn't initialize it with length. That's why you have 0 at the end of error message.

Comment: This wouldn't be the cause since the array is supplied by the method list() in libgdx's FIleHandle class (https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandle.html). That also doesn't explain why it works when running in eclipse, since eclipse would catch that.

Answer (score 0):

Since the list() method cannot be used on desktop applications, I will solve this issue by reading and writing the filenames in the songs directory to a text file.